# Is there a list of vague/meaningless tags with little to no usage guidance?

Tags: discussion, tags

The about for ['basic-concepts'](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/basic-concepts/info) is:

> THIS TAG IS MEANINGLESS, please don't use it. Pick something more specific and descriptive.

Likewise, the tag wiki is empty.

Similarly, the about sections and the tag wikis of ['accuracy'](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/accuracy/info) and ['methodology'](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/methodology/info) are empty.

All of them have a decent number of uses (+150), so I'm not certain that they *aren't* valuable to CV. But on the other hand, it's not clear to me either that they are.

Is there a thread somewhere which has a list of tags like this to suggest/nominate to bring to other people's attention?

Comment: [accuracy] is a fine tag, I assume it stands for classification accuracy. [methodology] sounds weird, I suspect it might be a useless tag, but this needs to be investigated.

Comment: Hi Chill2Macht. Is there any reason you didn't accept gung's answer? It looks quite comprehensive to me.

Answer (score 7):

[basic-concepts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic-concepts) is a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).  The tag for `[meta-tags]` on meta.SE defines them as "Meta tags are tags which describe something other than the question's content--such as the author's skill level, motivation, or current take on it".  The official SE policy is that they are not supposed to be allowed.  As such, `[basic-concepts]` probably should be (have been) burninated (see, [Do we need [basic-concepts] tag?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2854/7290)), but we don't seem to make much progress on that sort of thing (cf., [Tag-candidates for removal](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3031/7290)).

---

I think having excerpts / usage guides is more important than having wikis.  (Wikis are nice, but I'm not sure how many people ever even know they exist; in addition, there are probably tags that just don't really need any full wiki, but should still have an excerpt.)  Moreover, the more common a tag is, the more important it presumably is for it to have an excerpt, all else held equal.  From these points, a simple way to look for tags that need excerpts is to go to our [tags](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags) page, sort by `popular` (if not already), and then scan through page after page until you see one without an excerpt.  The first such tag I notice is [accuracy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accuracy) on page 6.

If you want a more formal method, you can use an existing data query (or make your own) at the Stack Exchange [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) site.  Navigate to the site, click on Cross Validated, and search using relevant terms.  People like making lots of 'forks' of these queries, which I often find less useful, so I sort by `popular`.  Here is a search for "[tag wiki](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/queries?order_by=popular&q=tag%20wiki)".  The top two hits are [What tag wikis can I edit?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/8201/what-tag-wikis-can-i-edit), and [Most common tags with short, long, or missing excerpt or wiki](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/445925/most-common-tags-with-short-long-or-missing-excerpt-or-wiki).  Both might have potential for you.  The only thing to bear in mind is that the data site is only updated on Sunday mornings at around 3:00 UTC, so the information returned by a query may be somewhat out of date when you use it.

For what it's worth, none of these strategies picks out "vague" or "meaningless" tags.  That would be a heavy lift for a SQL query (it reminds me of [this](https://xkcd.com/1425/)).

Comment: +1. I took a very brief look on [methodology] that OP mentioned, and it looks like an excellent candidate for burnination (with too many threads for manual removal). I should probably add it to the candidates-for-removal thread.